# take maximum value from field and subtract 1 row by row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to get value from service_total (this field came from a separate table), then I need to subtract 1 starting from the most current record inserted (this is highlighted in service_accrued field). I need to figure out how to calculate this service_accrued field into my query. I dont know how to take this service_total as a starting point and decrease by one row by row. This is obviously very easy to do in Excel, I am having trouble in sql.

[image]

Comment: So basically, you would like service total be exactly opposite compared to service_accrued? So service total will go 314, 313, 312, etc?

Comment: The service total will be constant because it is a total coming from a different table. The service accrued will go 314, 313, 312, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just had the table without `service_per_period` and `service_accrued` you could regenerate them using `row_number()`. This only works if `service_per_period` is a constant value.

```
select
    p_id,
    employee_id,
    name,
    pay_period_id,
    1 as service_per_period,
    service_total + 1 - row_number() over (
        partition by employee_id
        order by p_id desc
    ) service_accrued,
    service_total
from
    mytable
```

Comment: This solution seems to work! I really need to learn how 'row_number() over( partion by ' works. I may have to make modifications because I need to add in a field payroll_unit and then group by the field payroll_unit. When I do this grouping, it throws off the numbers the service_accrued field.